# whats the difference between Hide() and Visible=false?

Tags: c#, winforms

I can use the `Hide()` to hide form in a win app. but also I could use `Visible = false` to hide a form. if I use either way to show the hidden form I have to use `Visible = true`.

1. So which one should I use to hide the form, `Hide()` or `Visible = false?` and why?
2. What happens when I use `Hide()` to hide form?
3. what happens if I use `Close()` to hide a form?

Comment: It's often a good idea to look at those methods from the inside to see what makes them work when a question such as this pops up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference.

`Form` inherits from `Control`. `Control.Hide` is implemented like this:

```
public void Hide()
{
    this.Visible = false;
}
```

When you hide a form, you can show is using `Show`:

```
yourForm.Show();
```

..which is implemented as:

```
public void Show()
{
    this.Visible = true;
}
```

So it is personal preference. Just make sure you use them in pairs so it's nicer to read:

```
form.Hide();
form.Show();
```

..as opposed to..

```
form.Hide();
form.Visible = true;
```

When using `Close`.. you aren't hiding the form. You are literally sending a `WM_CLOSE` to the window.. removing it. `Dispose` is also called.

Answer (score 0):

1. If it's specifically your intention to hide the form then call Hide to make that clear.  If it's your intention to change the visibility of the form and the same code might do either then set Visible.
2. It disappears from view.  Presumably you wanted more than that but it's not clear what that is from your question.